# Thymeleaf th:block not working any more

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have written a block of code in `Thymeleaf`:

```
<th:block th:if="${i.mid} > ${yesterday.tableRateModel.rates[e.index].mid}">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></i>
                    </th:block>
                    <th:block th:if="${i.mid} == ${yesterday.tableRateModel.rates[e.index].mid}">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-small"></i>
                    </th:block>
                    <th:block th:if="${i.mid} < ${yesterday.tableRateModel.rates[e.index].mid}">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i>
                    </th:block>
```

And in this case I get error like:
`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The value of attribute "th:if" associated with an element type "th:block" must not contain the '<' character.`

But when I comment the last `th:block` everything works properly. What is wrong?

The problem is with `<`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
&lt; for <
&gt; for >
&le; for <=
&ge; for >=
```